# Using grep to match one digit with TCL

Tags: regex, grep, tcl

The file that I want to grep contains many lines.

I want to grep lines which contain only 1 digit: "0" or "1".

I used this command:

```
exec grep -e "^\[0-1\]{1}$" file
```

But I got:

```
child process exited abnormally
```

What's wrong with RegExp of grep?

Answer (score 1):

The most common issue when running `grep` as a Tcl subprocess is that it exits with a non-zero error code when it doesn't find anything at all. This always causes Tcl to throw an exception. The simplest workaround is perhaps this:

```
exec /bin/sh -c {grep -e '^[0-1]{1}$'; true} < file
```

Note that we are feeding in the file using a redirection here; this means that it is not necessary to strip the name of the file from the results.

Comment: Other approaches might be reasonably considered too, such as using `sed` or doing the entire search in a few lines of Tcl code (which may be faster and will certainly be more portable to non-POSIX platforms).

Comment: I got  the same problem

Comment: `exec sed -n {/^[01]$/p} file`